# Spotify app failure to load

Tags: spotify

I have looked extensively through SO, but have yet to find any help with this question, despite trying almost every recommendation.

https://github.com/danwaz/powerhour

trying to install this app on Spotify. I do have a developer account, and have created the necessary dir in ~/documents/Spotify

For whatever reason, I am shown a loading bar when I attempt to load the app according to how the manifest details the bundle. I do get a "metadata started" message, but nothing loads...it just sits there spinning its' wheels.

Any recommendations from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you on?

If you're on a Mac or Linux, the folder should be `~/Spotify`, where `~` is your home directory.

If you're on Windows, it should be in the `Spotify` directory of your `My Documents` folder.

Comment: Tried that, still no luck  =(